# Подскажите, что я не так написал

Tags: c++, xcode, byte, bit

Ошибка в вызове функции show_binary, не могу понять в чем именно проблема ( No matching function for call to 'show_binary' ) ( функция выполняет анализ каждого бита в младшем байте переменной )

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void show_binary(unsigned int u);
int main () {
    show_binary();
}
void show_binary(unsigned int u){
int t;
 for(t=128; t > 0; t = t/2)
     if(u & t) cout << "1 ";
     else cout << "0 ";
 cout << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта ошибка значит, что вы передали неправильные агрументы для работы функции. Ваша функция ждёт переменную типа `unsigned int`, а вы пытаетесь вызвать её из main без аргумента. Замените `show_binary();` на `show_binary(сюда вашу переменную или число, которую нужно использовать в функции);`. Либо уберите переменную из объявления функции. `void show_binary();`

Comment: Вы который раз путаете понятия `(:` "пытаетесь вызвать её из main без переменной" – без *аргумента*, а аргументом может быть как значение из переменной, так и просто числовое значение или даже выражение. Переменная вовсе не обязательна.

Comment: @AivanF. спасибо, я исправил `:)`